# PHP search keywords in multiple table column

Tags: php, search, multiple-columns

I have below search script to perform multiple column search in table, but the results is not as expected, few of data rows are show with status = `new` and company name = `demo`, can someone please point out what is wrong for below query? what is more accurate query to perform a search with these conditions?

```
SELECT * FROM messageboard AS m LEFT JOIN users AS u ON m.author_id=u.user_id 
WHERE m.status='approved' 
AND u.user_email LIKE '%demo%' 
OR u.company_name LIKE '%demo%' 
OR m.subject LIKE '%demo%' 
ORDER BY m.posted_time DESC
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM messageboard AS m LEFT JOIN users AS u ON m.author_id=u.user_id 
WHERE m.status='approved' 
AND (u.user_email LIKE '%demo%' 
OR u.company_name LIKE '%demo%' 
OR m.subject LIKE '%demo%' )
ORDER BY m.posted_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest organize your AND and OR conditions with brackets.